Чему будет равно значение переменной sum1 после выполнения следующего фрагмента кода?
sum1 = 0 
for i in range(20): 
    if ((i % 2 == 0) and (i % 3 == 0)) or (i % 5 == 0): 
        sum1 += i


Вы можете в уме это посчитать, или запустить программу и посмотреть вывод. Почему нас-то спрашиваете?

@MBo Видимо, человек перепутал SO с ChatGPT ))

Я школьник Девятиклассник, ответ не могу найти по этому зашел сюда

@АлексейИванов, ответ по сути не нужно "искать", нужно просто добавить вывод результата через print в конце и запустить эту программу с помощью python. Очень просто сделать. Сложно - если не пытаться.

Варианты решения задачи:

Запустить любой онлайн-питон (их сейчас довольно много, с десяток точно есть), например Google Colab, скопировать туда код, запустить, вывести в конце на печать эту переменную print(sum1).
Задача на самом деле сводится к такой: "Найти сумму чисел, делящихся либо на 5 либо на 2 и 3 одновременно (т.е. делящихся на 6) в диапазоне 0-19." В этом диапазоне не так много таких чисел, вы их можете "вручную" перебрать: 5, 10, 15 и 6, 12, 18. Сложить их можете сами, даже в уме. 0 среди этих чисел тоже, кстати, будет, но он общую сумму не меняет.

